# Apex replay debugger, which log file?

Tags: apex, debugging

I'm trying to use the replay debugger and it seems like it would work great if I could easily find which log file just got created.  I'm just doing one operation through the salesforce application (not a test class), and it seems 10 logs get created.  I immediately turned off log creation.  I eventually found it using the dev console and using the raw output, but it was a slow process.

Any tips on an easier way to finding the right log file?

Comment: a given transaction might spawn several async transactions and each will have their own log file